# OpenGLRenderer is out of memory

Tags: android, user-interface, tablelayout

I am trying to create a table layout filled with lots of bits of data, the table layout is inside a scroll view.

I am using this to fill it

```
TableLayout tl;

.....

tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

.....
```

and when I set it I create a new Text View to put into it like so

```
TextView tv;

....

tr = new TableRow(Context);

.....
tv = new TextView(Context);
tv.setText(progress[1]);
tr.addView(tv);
...
tl.addView(tr);
```

A new text row is created when I have put 12 text views in it and the tr is added to the tl when it has 12 views in it.

The font size of the text view is default, all I do to the text view you see here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider changing to a viewgroup that can recycle/reuse its child views, such as a listview or gridview. That way you won't need to keep everything in memory.

Comment: It needs to be a table view for alignment and because it is straight forward

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's due to the amount of data? Does it work with less data?

Comment: Yeah it wasnt the amount of data been put in, it was just the order that it was in it seemed