# mmap failed - GL error: Out of memory

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, out-of-memory, android-scrollview

Have a fragment implemented that has multiple horizontal scrollviews. When i scroll it multiple times it simply blacks out and on popback the complete application gets blacked out, until the system creates a new instance of activity.

*To be noted* : **Not** using hardware accelerator

Couldn't understand a thing given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33897711/android-mmap-fails-with-out-of-memory).
Tried to lookup [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043125/openglrenderer-is-out-of-memory) not an option have to use scroll view

**`LOGCAT`**

```
01-20 21:35:18.737 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1971>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
01-20 21:35:18.737 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 W/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_ldd_control:475>: ioctl fd 27 code 0x40080921 (IOCTL_KGSL_SHAREDMEM_FREE) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
01-20 21:35:18.746 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:2260>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
01-20 21:35:18.748 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1971>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
01-20 21:35:18.757 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:2260>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
01-20 21:35:18.759 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1971>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
01-20 21:35:18.768 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 W/Adreno-GSL: <sharedmem_gpumem_alloc_id:2260>: sharedmem_gpumem_alloc: mmap failed errno 12 Out of memory
01-20 21:35:18.770 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 E/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_memory_alloc_pure:1971>: GSL MEM ERROR: kgsl_sharedmem_alloc ioctl failed.
01-20 21:35:18.770 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 W/Adreno-GSL: <gsl_ldd_control:475>: ioctl fd 27 code 0x40080921 (IOCTL_KGSL_SHAREDMEM_FREE) failed: errno 22 Invalid argument
01-20 21:35:18.778 29857-30181/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 E/OpenGLRenderer: GL error:  Out of memory!
01-20 21:35:53.215 29857-29857/com.amplitude.tron.volksradio22 W/SplitWindow: update focus...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the OOM exception covered by adding this to the manifest :

> android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: Got that error when was testing my app on android TV emulator a couple of times, heap thingy helped, thanks!

Comment: still getting issue after adding above line

Comment: This will not work if a OOM issue is occurred, it just defer the time to happen. So this is not the root cause for my case.